# Scroll an element inside the window, which has scrollbars.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at this link:

[Scrolling with outer div vertically and inner div horizontally but also hiding the scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160357/scrolling-with-outer-div-vertically-and-inner-div-horizontally-but-also-hiding-t)

For the selector:

```
$('pre[class="default prettyprint prettyprinted"]')[4]
```

you will find an element (code section), which has scrollbars.

Is is possible in js/Jquery to perform scroll down to those sort of elements?

I know to scroll the main window, you can use:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("div[name='appGrid']").offset().top}, 2000);
```

or similar, but how about scrolling inner elements which has scroll bars?

Comment: Have you tried: 
$('pre[class="default prettyprint prettyprinted"]')[4].animate({scrollTop: 200}, 2000); ?

Comment: Wow, that works. But it doesn't go till the end, but it works

Comment: It's because of the 200 in the code above, you need to set it to $('pre[class="default prettyprint prettyprinted"]').height()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Jonas's suggestion, you might also consider using the [jQuery scrollTo plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo).  It takes care of many advanced cases for scrolling in overflow elements.

Demo: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/