# How hide the scrollbar in overflow:scroll CSS

Tags: css

I need to a scroll-able div but the scroll bar is hidden here is my code. Thanks for the help. I found this and tried but it doesn't seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/

**CSS**

```
.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_right {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 670px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_right .conatiner_hidden_scroll_2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_right .conatiner_hidden_scroll_2 .container_center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_right .conatiner_hidden_scroll_2 .container_center .profile_img_pentagon {
  width: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_right .conatiner_hidden_scroll_2 p {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg_info_profile">
    <div class="bg_profile_left">
        asdfas dfasdf asdf asdfasdfas dfasdfas dfasdfasdf
        asdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfas dfasdfasdfa sdfasdf
        asdfasd fasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfa sdfasdfasdf
        asdf asdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasd fasdfasdf                
        asdfas dfas dfasd fasdfasdfasd fasdfa sdfa sdfasdf
    </div>
    <div class="bg_profile_right">
        <div class="conatiner_hidden_scroll_2">
            <div class="container_center">
                <!-- Some code -->
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p>asdfas dfasdf asdf asdfasdfas dfasdfas dfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfas dfasdfasdfa sdfasdf
            asdfasd fasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfa sdfasdfasdf
            asdf asdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasd fasdfasdf                
            asdfas dfas dfasd fasdfasdfasd fasdfa sdfa sdfasdf</p>
            <p>asdfas dfasdf asdf asdfasdfas dfasdfas dfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfas dfasdfasdfa sdfasdf
            asdfasd fasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfa sdfasdfasdf
            asdf asdfasdfa sdfasdfasdfa sdfasdfasd fasdfasdf                
            asdfas dfas dfasd fasdfasdfasd fasdfa sdfa sdfasdf</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the output
The right side(white)
[image]

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684403/hide-scrollbar-with-overflowscroll-enabled/

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar is an OS element, and it is not possible to override its output when using `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;`.

That said, the scroll bar will disappear on many touch screen devices, and Macs (with default system settings).

You can kind of hide them if you were to make the `overflow: scroll;` slightly wider than a parent with `overflow: hidden;`. Permanently visible scroll bars have a common width of `24px`, but that can vary. Also this would make it less obvious to the visitor that the element is scrollable, not to mention impossible to scroll at all if they have neither a multi-touch trackpad nor scroll wheel.

From a standards and accessibility perspective this is a bad idea. If you must have custom control over the scroll bar for an element you should look in to a Javascript library which offers the behaviour you desire.